# Changing the Session Languge leads to "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: datetime, parsing, parseexception, java-calendar, unparseable

whenever I'm defining the timeframe being in German session language after changing to English lang. session (and vice versa) I'm getting the:
**java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10.10.2018"**

Here is the fragment:

```
    Date startDateFormatted = DateUtils.convertDateToMinusDayNumber(cal, dayRange);
    Date endDateFormatted = new Date();

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(startDate) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(endDate))
    {
        try
        {
            String datePattern = getLocalizedString("dd.MM.yyyy"); // 
            startDateFormatted = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern).parse(startDate); // exception is throwing on this line
            endDateFormatted = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern).parse(endDate);
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            LOG.error(ERROR_DATE_PARSING, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There must be a problem with the function, `getLocalizedString`. Post its definition.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Could you please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Asking because we cannot run your code as it stands to see what happens and analyse it, and because you haven’t provided enough information for us to tell what’s wrong. A minimal and complete example would satisfy both.

Comment: Have you checked your `startDate` string for any non-printing characters?

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.

```
    String datePattern = "dd.MM.uuuu";
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern);
    
    String startDateString = "10.10.2018";
    
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(startDateString, dateFormatter);
    
    System.out.println(startDate);
```

Output:

> 2018-10-10

If you want to support different date formats for different locales, let Java handle that part for you:

```
    String datePattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
            FormatStyle.MEDIUM, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, Locale.GERMAN);
```

German locale works with your example string of `10.10.2018`. For UK locale, for example, a string like `10 Oct 2018` would be required instead, as Britons would typically expect.

### What went wrong in your code?

We cannot tell from the information and code that you have provided exactly what happened. A couple of good guesses are:

1. As Arvind Kumar Avinash said in a comment, `getLocalizedString()` may be causing trouble. You may print `datePattern` to check. Localization is something you do to strings that you display to the user. Trying to localize a format pattern string for a formatter is probably plain wrong, so you should leave out that method call. That the error occurs when changing language seems to support this possibility.
2. There may be unexpected non-printing characters in your string. One way to check would be to print `startDate.length()`. If the length is greater than 10, there are more characters than the 10 chars in `10.10.2018`.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.